# Mir the X Server replacement

Tags: performance, xserver, porting, mir

I read much about the X Server replacement Mir, but I am not quite sure which benefits it will have. Ok it is a newer technologie, the currently used X server uses code that is twenty years old or even older. So I have some questions targeting this topic:

1. Will Mir also replace X server and Wayland in other distributions?
2. When could we expect the first Ubuntu using Mir?
3. Will it be easier to port Ubuntu to a new device when Mir is used?
4. Could we expect some performance enhancements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether mir will be used in other distro is totally depend upon respective distro maintainers.

Mir is ubuntu's own display server to meet some future requirement that ubuntu have. Like seamless experience across devices.

It was told, first MIR will be implemented in ubuntu touch then will replace in desktop. There is no confirmed date, most probably 14.04

3rd question doesn't really mean anything to me. Ubuntu is already available for various devices (ARM, x64, powerpc). Which port you are talking about.

I think, for performance we should sit back and watch. As a first implementation definitely we should not expect huge performance improvement.

You can read why MIR is being created and it's status over here

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MirSpec